# Populate spinner based on selection in other spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying to get data from server into spinner, my json object is

```
{"result":{"AndhrPradesh":["Jayamahal","ABC","JP nagar"],"Mumbai":["XYZ","PQR"],"Pune":["123","Hi"]}}
```

I am able to get the values AndhraPradesh,Mumbai and Pune in one spinner. now my problem is after selecting city i want to display  corresponding data in that city.
for example, if select Mumbai from one spinner i want to display XYZ,PQR in another spinner, Please help me.

Comment: Provide some code for modifications

Comment: Create a container to hold the relevant information to the cities and pass it to the second spinner.

Answer (score 0):

First of all parse the json data like

```
JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray cityName= jsonObject.getJSONArray("AndhrPradesh")
for(i=0;i<cityName.length();i++){
//your inner string of the Array
}
```

Then

```
citynameSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //here set the values to another spinner
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, here my city names are changed dynamically through server ,based on city selection i need to display corresponding data from server.thanks in advance any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code snippet

```
public class SpinnerFilterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
private Spinner mMainSPN;
private ArrayList<String> mSpinnerArray;
private Map<String,ArrayList<String>> innterDataMap;
private Spinner mInnerSPN;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSpinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    innterDataMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    mMainSPN = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_main);
    mInnerSPN = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_inner);

    mMainSPN.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String key = mSpinnerArray.get(position);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerFilterActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,innterDataMap.get(key));
            mInnerSPN.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    parseJson();
}

private void parseJson() {
    String s= "{\"result\":{\"AndhrPradesh\":[\"Jayamahal\",\"ABC\",\"JP nagar\"],\"Mumbai\":[\"XYZ\",\"PQR\"],\"Pune\":[\"123\",\"Hi\"]}}\n";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONObject obj= jsonObject.getJSONObject("result");
        Iterator<String> stringIterator = obj.keys();
        while (stringIterator.hasNext()){
            String key = stringIterator.next();
            mSpinnerArray.add(key);
            JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray(key);
            ArrayList<String> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                innerList.add(String.valueOf(jsonArray.get(i)));
            }
            innterDataMap.put(key,innerList);
        }
        populateDataInSpinner();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void populateDataInSpinner() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,mSpinnerArray);
    mMainSPN.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
  }
}
```

In this code I have kept a data in 2 fields one i mSpinnerArray to display the aster list and other is map in which inner list is kept on behalf of the key as parent value. Whenever onOptionItemSelected method gets called I fetch the list of inner data from map on behalf of the seleted item from the master list as it is working as a key in innerMap data. I hope I am clear. Let me know if there is any problem.